# Very different static gps tests for different devices

Tags: gps, mobile

I don't understand the results that I got when I measured with three different devices that were lying on the ground for couple of hours.
These devices were: Nexus 10 tablet, Samsung Galaxy Core Prime smartphone and Samsung Galaxy Tab (quite old tablet). I can add more info if needed.

These devices were lying right next to each other (which means that the receivers were few centimeters from each other). I used the app GPS Logger (it has red symbol in Google Play) to capture the coordinates for couple of hours.

Here is the graph with all the points:
[image: Graph of what all the devices measured.]

So my question is, why did Nexus 10 (the middle blue color) measure with such an error shooting points everywhere and constantly shifting while Core prime (light blue) was moving slowly over couple of hours just wandering around and Galaxy Tab (dark blue) was just switching points after tens of minutes with no path whatsoever? Why is there such a difference and what causes it?

Other info: it was a clear day and I measured for over 6 hours.

Comment: I'd presume this is because the devices may have each selected a different set of satellites. Also, the phones could user additional/different sources such as WiFi for positioning.
But I'm not knowledgable enough about GPS to give an proper answer.

Comment: Later though, I used two HTC One M8s and Nexus 10 and the HTCs showed similar behavior as Core Prime while Nexus was scattered all over the place. Here I especially checked so that they only used GPS and no WiFi or BlueTooth. Different set of satellites is out of question I think because it was happening for hours and hours.

Comment: The quality of the receivers, the internal clocks, the data processing method, etc. varies from device to device. Also, how many data points do you have for each device? Did you set the logger to record at the same interval for all 3?

Comment: One possibility for the behavior of the Nexus is that its internal GPS solver may have used a smaller set of raw data and/or satellites for each position calculation compared to the other 2. Also, the quality of each individual receiver affects the quality of the received data, which in turn affects the subset of data chosen for processing, leading to a different result.

Comment: Yes those are the same intervals +- few minutes (meaning one started at lets say 9:15 another 9:18). All three have roughly 24000 data points.

Since the tablet Galaxy Tab is the oldest one I would expect it to be the most scattered one then which is not the case. While I do not know how it was on this exact measurement I can try to check if Nexus tends to have less satellites than Core Prime for example.

Comment: More scattered points do not necessarily mean worse reception or an older device. There is a whole lot of processing going on before the gps outputs a position, and from what I've read, the app that you used might be doing other near real-time post-processing on top of that. Did you have an option to enable static or dynamic mode in the app?

Comment: A good way to check your reception would be to log raw data into a [RINEX File](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.geopp.rinexlogger). Then you could really see how many observations and satellites the device had, and post-process the data to get better positioning and assess quality. However, I believe you need at least Android 7 to output raw data and some devices may not be compatible.

Comment: But I used the same app on all devices also I tested to see if different apps output different coordinates but they do not, so I think they just call some system functions. There is no option for dynamic or static mode.

Sadly I can not use the app because my devices are not compatible but thanks for the link I actually thought that it was impossible to get raw data on a phone.